# FTP user management system

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ftp

I want to build C#, WPF application for FTP user management.  It is getting difficult than what i thought initially.

Requirement is pretty simple: 
I should be able to create users and should be able to control their access to folders.

Not able to find out specific classes in .net so not sure where shall i start from.

Any link or sample available on this?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ujjwal

Comment: The FTP server would have to expose it's user database through an API or offer one for it's own use.  IIS 7 supposedly exposes this for custom accounts.  Serv-u has an API to use your database. If we knew your server, you might get a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTP as a protocol doesn't provide any means for managing users, neither servers support such mechanisms. If you have your own FTP/FTPS server implementation, you can make use of custom commands (but you will need a client-side protocol implementation that supports custom commands). If you want to manage users of existing FTP servers, then I am afraid you are out of luck.